# Let $f\in R[x]$ be quasiregular. The coefficients of its quasi-inverse $g$ are contained in the subring generated by the coefficients of $f$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Full question:

Let $f(x)\in R[x]$ have $0$ constant term and suppose $f(x)$ is quasi-regular with quasi-inverse $g(x)$. Show that the coefficients of $g(x)$ are contained in the subring generated by the coefficients of $f(x)$.

---

Exercise 5 p.393 from Basic Algebra II by Nathan Jacobson.

Here's my attempt, I just don't know how to finish it:

Let $f$ be quasi-regular and $g=1-(1-f)^{-1}$. We have $(1-f)(1-g)=1$, so $f+g-fg=0$, so $g=f(g-1)$ and so $g$ and $f$ only differ by a unit.

If $f=\sum a_ix^i$, then since $1-f$ is invertible, $1-a_0$ is a unit of $R$ (so $a_0$ is quasi-regular) and $a_i$ is nilpotent for $i>0$. I also showed that $f-a_0$ is nilpotent.

How do I finish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you go straight to calculation.

Let $(1 - f_1x - \cdots - f_n x^n)(g_0 + g_1x + \cdots + g_nx^m) = 1$.

Expanding the left side and comparing coefficients you get lots of relations:

$g_0 = 1$

$g_1 - g_0f_1 = 0$

$g_2 - g_1f_1 - g_0f_2 = 0$

and so on...

Note that you can always write the $i$th relation as

$$g_i = \text{a polynomial in $f_j$, $g_k$ with $j \leq i, k < i$}$$ which means that once you know that $g_k$ is in the subring generated by the coefficients of $f$ for $k < i$, you also know that $g_i$ is in the desired subring.

Can you finish it from here?